# Maximun sum path in a 2D matrix using Dynamic Programming in Matlab

Tags: matlab, max, dynamic-programming

Deal Altruists,

I am trying to find the maximum sum path in a 2D square matrix of NxN from the top left(0,0) to bottom right(N-1,N-1). I can move to any 8 possible directions from a point (i,j) to (i+1,j),(i,j+1),(i+1,j+1),(i-1,j),(i,j-1),(i-1,j-1),(i+1,j-1) and (i-1,j+1) if the possible direction are within matrix dimention range. All the elements of the matrix are positive and there is no repition in elements.

I tried the following method in MATLAB and getting weird results, i.e. getting only two directions out of possible 8. [for example click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha4gw.jpg)
P.S. It will also be helpful if I can get maximum sum path to any point in the matrix

```
     %% Main Dynamic Programming
     A=int8(100*round((rand(5,5)),2)); % Cost Matrix
     dp=zeros(size(A)); % Secondary matrix for keeping track of the costwhile 
                % traversing
     direction=[1 1;0 1;1 0;-1 -1; -1 1;1 -1;-1 0;0 -1];% 8 possible move
     for i=1:length(A)
         for j=1:length(A)
           neighbor_points=zeros(length(direction),2); 
           cost=zeros(1,length(direction));
           current_point=[i j];
           for n=1:length(direction)
               neighbor_points(n,:)=current_point+direction(n,:);
               neighborX =neighbor_points(n,1);
               neighborY =neighbor_points(n,2);
                    if(neighborX >=1 && neighborX <=size_grid && neighborY 
                        >=1 && neighborY <=size_grid)

                          cost(n)=dp(neighborX, neighborY);

                    end
            end
           [~,ind]=max(cost); 
           dp(i,j)=A(i,j)+dp(neighbor_points(ind,1),neighbor_points(ind,2));
           fprintf('dp(%d,%d) is updated to %f.\n',i,j,dp(i,j));
       end
   end

       %% Back Tracking from end point to start point
      ii=1;
      end_point=[length(A) length(A)];
      Traject(ii,:)=end_point;
      current_point=end_point;
      while ii>0
      ii=ii+1;
      back_track=dp(current_point(1),current_point(2))- 
      A(current_point(1),current_point(2));

      k=find(abs(dp-back_track)<10^-6) ;
      [i, j] = ind2sub(size(A),k);
      new_point=[i j];
     disp(back_track)
     %disp(new_point)
     Traject(ii,:)=new_point;
       if new_point(1)==1 && new_point(2)==1
            break

       end
    current_point=new_point;


   end
    Trajectory=Traject;
```

I am new to dynamic programming area and thus seeking help from experts. Maybe there is a problem with my algorithm. Thanks in advance

Comment: "weird results" is not a well defined problem. Please give us a reproducible issue with example inputs and expected outputs rather than random inputs and unspecified outputs

Comment: Sorry for my bad interpretation, I am moving only in two directions (i,j+1) and (i+1,j-1) out of 8. I tried for different cost matrix but no help

Comment: Hi Wolfie, I edited the post and attached a picture for convenience

Comment: The longest path problem is NP-hard. I wouldn't expect any O(n^2) algorithm to solve it.

Comment: Can you kindly provide pseudocode for O(n^3) algorithm

Comment: No, I can't. For two reasons: 1) that's not what Stack Overflow is for, and 2) NP-hard implies that, in the general case, there is no polynomial-time algorithm that will produce exact solutions. For future reference, unless you tag the person you're addressing (like @beaker), they won't know you've responded to them. Please also take the time to take the [Tour] and read [ask] .